# How can I use spring to fire off an asynchronous batch task?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

Basically I would like to do some multithreading in my spring java program and I don't know how to use my servers spring resources to create a new thread.

I looked at [Any good Spring threading with a TaskExecutor examples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852743/any-good-spring-threading-with-a-taskexecutor-examples) but I couldn't figure out where the original `TaskExecutor` came from, like how would I pass that into the class?

Also is `TaskExecutor` the best thing to use for just creating another thread in my program?

Comment: You mention Spring and Server...any more details on what sort of app this is? Is it a web-app? A desktop app? Some other sort of web service app? A generic processing app that doesn't really have much of a UI (along the lines of a command-line app)?

Answer (score 0):

The TaskExecutor is defined in the xml spring beans definition and passed as constructor's argument to the utility class.

```
 <constructor-arg type="org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor" ref="taskExecutor" />
```

If you have the choice, you should definitely work with TaskExecutor and Threadpool instead of  managing your thread the old way.

Comment: But how do I actually invoke the new class that I have when I don't have a TaskExecutor to pass into it?

Comment: both TaskExecutor and somethingThatShouldHappenInAThread are created by Spring, you just have to get a ref (by injection into your service layer for example) on somethingThatShouldHappenInAThread and do classWithMethodToFire.run().

Answer (score 0):

The post that you mention gives a good example of what you want to do. taskExecutor is injected via the constructor. Checkout the spring beans configuration given in that post. I believe it is a good practice to use TaskExecutor.