# Spring MVC How to use AsyncTaskExecutor from Controller

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-mvc, asynchronous, callable

I need to execute some code from the Controller in different threads.

My structure:

```
@Controller
MyController

    //invoked from frontend
    @RequestMapping
    MyMethod 
       Loop
           future = asyncTaskExecutor.Submit(callable)
       End loop
       Get future results
    End MyMethod
```

I am using AsyncTaskExecutor like in this example:

[Any good Spring threading with a TaskExecutor examples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852743/any-good-spring-threading-with-a-taskexecutor-examples)

```
public SendEmailController() {}

public SendEmailController(AsyncTaskExecutor asyncTaskExecutor) {
super();
this.asyncTaskExecutor = asyncTaskExecutor;
}
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="sendEmailController" class="com.ts.bpu.email.web.SendEmailController">
    <constructor-arg ref="asyncTaskExecutor" />
</bean>

<bean id="asyncTaskExecutor"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="queueCapacity" value="25" />
</bean>
```

But the constructor with the parameter never is used. But if I use only the constructor with parameter the exception trace is:

```
 GRAVE: WebModule[/TsSecPricesEngineWeb]StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sendEmailController' defined in file [C:\Sun\AppServer\domains\domain1\applications\j2ee-modules\TsSecPricesEngineWeb\WEB-INF\classes\com\ts\bpu\email\web\SendEmailController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.ts.bpu.email.web.SendEmailController]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.ts.bpu.email.web.SendEmailController.<init>()
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:965)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:270)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1194)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:848)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:287)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:218)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:94)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1096)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1096)
at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:288)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(DefaultProcessorTask.java:647)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.doProcess(DefaultProcessorTask.java:579)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.process(DefaultProcessorTask.java:831)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.executeProcessorTask(DefaultReadTask.java:341)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:263)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:214)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:265)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ssl.SSLWorkerThread.run(SSLWorkerThread.java:106)

 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.ts.bpu.email.web.SendEmailController]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.ts.bpu.email.web.SendEmailController.<init>()
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:70)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:958)
... 44 more

 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.ts.bpu.email.web.SendEmailController.<init>()
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2706)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:1985)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:65)
... 45 more
```

Any Suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: If the constructor is never invoked it probably means the bean is never created.  Can you declare a default constructor and see if that is being called.  If neither are called then there is a problem with your application context in which it isn't being loaded

Comment: The option that i have tried is: Use two Constructors, One without parameters and other with the asyncTaskExecutor as parameter. With this option, and the applicationContext.xml like i have shown, the second constructor never was used

Comment: If I use only one contructor with the asyncTaskExecutor as parameter, I get an error in the compilation.

Comment: In the default constructor set this.asyncTaskExecutor = null and see if that constructor is every being called.  Put in a println to ensure its being called

Comment: John, I have completed my question with the trace exception when i use only the constructor with one parameter

Comment: I will inject the taskExecutor as a property.

Answer (score 0):

When Spring container start it will call your SendEmailController class constructor.

Comment: Yes, I know it, Are there alternative to get an instance of asyncTaskExecutor?