# Spring Batch : multi file processing using multi threads

Tags: spring, csv, batch-processing

I have requirement where I have to deal with multiple files (say 300 csv files).

I need to read --> process --> write, each individual file as I need to apply some transformation logic on the data.

For each input file there would be a corresponding transformed file. so for 300 input files we would have 300 output files.
At the end, all the 300 output files are needed to be merged into a single file which would be compressed and then transferred to a remote location over FTP/SFTP.

Say, every hour we would have to deal with a new set of 300 file on which we would be required to apply the above processing, so we would be scheduling the above job per hour.

1. How to handle multi file processing in the above scenario using Spring Batch ?
2. How to make the above processing to happen in multiple threads ?

Please suggest.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring [task execution and scheduling](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-task-namespace) and then use java [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/853003/1006863) here at SO for a very simple example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will look into the links and update you soon.