# Spring - Ensure Thread Pooling

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, pooling

The question is How to ensure that we can control how many concurrent calls there can be towards any given system from Spring application?

Secondary how to provide such functionality?

Does Spring already has such mechanism?

I have basic knowledge about FixedThreadPool but no clue how to implement such thing.

'Calls' as web service calls to external systems and subsystems.
'concurrent calls' - running at the same time - I don't know if that description helps.

Java/Spring based enterprise application - I'm new in project so I have huge lack of information yet.

What I've noticed till now it uses spring in version 4.x
context, web, webmvc, core, aspects, aop, beans, orm, jdbc, context-support,

Comment: you might need to check this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/852743/any-good-spring-threading-with-a-taskexecutor-examples)

Comment: What kind of **Spring Application**? What all Spring APIs that application use that you are calling it a **Spring Application**? Also, what do you mean by **concurrent calls**? What kind of calls are those, web service calls, function calls? As far as I can understand, using thread pool has nothing to do with number of calls since I can start threads from within a thread. API utilizing thread pools should be mindful of number of calls its generating but first **call** needs to be clarified.

Comment: @Sabir Khan, your comment helped me to update the answer

Comment: What about (Web/Enterprise)Server?

Comment: @SundararajGovindasamy - apache-tomee-1.7.2

Comment: Did you get the chance to try my solution? ;-) . tomee is tomcat++.

Comment: @SundararajGovindasamy I tried your solution, but I think it's just temporary solutions till I will know better what I want :)
--probably that sounds strange--

Comment: When you are not sure what you want, no one can solve it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using **tomcat**,In **server.xml** file you specify **maxThreads** which specifies maximum number of simultaneous requests that can be handled. Refer the documentation [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html).

```
<Connector port="8080" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
               enableLookups="false" redirectPort="4443" acceptCount="100"
               debug="0" connectionTimeout="60000" 
               disableUploadTimeout="true" />
```

if you are using embeded tomcat (ie.Spring [Boot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties)), you can set the max threads as below.

```
server.tomcat.max-threads = 300
```